# What are the different graph processing alternatives for Hadoop/Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, graph, bigdata

Giraph, GraphX, Neo4J are some solutions today I am aware of. As this is an area all the tech-giants are working, an updated list is much appreciated. The good comparison of the tools listed above is also not seen anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I should mention that Giraph and GraphX are for graph processing and Neo4j is a graph database. If you are going to store your graph and query it like "give me some nodes that have content 'X' with two distance neighbor having content 'Y'" solutions like Neo4j (graph database) should be applied. Otherwise, Giraph and GraphX could play graph processing role.
Unfortunately, although GraphX offer very nice APIs, for large graph size it fails when available distributed memory is not enough. This condition is mostly observed when the size of intermediate data could not be fit in the available memory.
In addition, as represented in the literatures, Giraph often got the worst place in the performance but it is more stable than GraphX.
There are other solutions like [GraphLab](https://turi.com/products/create/) and [Titan](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/) for "Distributed Graph Processing" which are valuable to investigate.

Comment: GraphLab link takes to Apple turicreate (https://github.com/apple/turicreate/) which doesn't seem graph related.